# Steam does not open window when using launcher icon (22.04 LTS)

Tags: steam

When I start Steam using the app launch icon, it quickly appears in the docker panel but then disappears almost immediately again. It does not open a window. And then the process repeats indefinitely. Luckily I can stop this because the Steam icon is displayed in the Activities bar. What can I do to fix this and open Steam from the launcher? Which logs could be relevant here?

Further info:

- Starting Steam works fine when I trigger it from the terminal.
- Reinstallation of the Steam client did not help.
- This behavior appeared after I've switched from Cinnamon to Gnome desktop yesterday.
- I found some posts about a similar issue but there they report that the graphics driver was the cause (either NVidia or recently updated). However, I have an AMD card and I've used the same driver version from the beginning:
- GPU & driver: Radeon 7800 XT (Radeon Software for Linux, version 23.20.00.48 for Ubuntu 22.04.3 HWE with ROCm 5.7)
- Output of `xrandr --listproviders`: `Providers: number: 0`

Comment: Did you check answer 1409465?  Seems PrefersNonDefaultGPU gets confused sometimes.

Comment: @ubfan1 The value was PrefersNonDefaultGPU = true and I changed it to false. However, that did not help. Same issue behavior.

Comment: Please include in your original posting the output of:  xrandr --listproviders    That's another place source/sink can get mixed up, although if so, don't know how a terminal launch would work.  Is your settings for power set for performance?  That used to make a difference, but not sure it does anymore.

Comment: Output added. I don't have a power setting "Performance". Only "Balanced" (-> selected) and "Power Saving"

Comment: At login, when the password field is present, click on the little gear icon in the lower right, and select the non-wayland choice (ubuntu or xorg). Then redo the xrandr and see what's changed. I can run under wayland, but at a slower frame rate.  (But I use Nvidia, no experience with Radeon).

Comment: I changed to "Ubuntu on Xorg". Starting Steam worked there. But the real banger is that when I switched back to "Ubuntu" (i.e. using Wayland) Steam was able to open via launcher again! Wohoo! No idea why idea it works now but it does. Thanks!